# Using a ref to find and scroll to the top position of child element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope my approach to this is correct but I am trying to build a component in React where a bunch of posts are rendered in a column view stacked on top of one another, each individual post is set to 100vh.

**Psuedo Code**

```
<container ref={postRef}>
   <post 1/>
   <post 2/>
   <post 3/>
</container>
```

I have a `ref` on the `<container/>` and from another component's `onClick` function I get the current index of the `<post/>` I clicked on, and then find that element in the dom.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (postRef.current && indexOfClickedPost) {
      const refBounds = postRef.current.children[indexOfClickedPost].getBoundingClientRect()

      window.scrollTo({
        top: // which unit goes here?
      });
    }
  })
```

my end goal is to scroll my `<container/>` component to the very top of the post relative to the one that was just clicked.

Ex. if the user clicks a post with an index of 2, the page will scroll to where the post 2 div begins

I am not sure which unit I am to put in my `window.scrollTo` to get that effect. Putting `refBounds.top` does not yield the results I want, it seems to be doing nothing at all from what I can visibly see. Any advice would be great. Thanks!

Comment: That's feaseable, but did you evaluate if maybe it would be enough the classic hash navigation? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xxeygg?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose two different approaches, the first one follows your trial, and it makes use of `getBoundingClientRect()` to calculate the right distance from top and `scrollTo` to scroll to that element:

```js
function App() {
  const [currPostIdx, setCurrPostIdx] = useState(0);
  const containerRef = useRef();

  const selectPost = (idx) => {
    setCurrPostIdx(idx);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const el = containerRef.current.children[currPostIdx];
    const top = window.pageYOffset + el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    console.log(currPostIdx, top);
    window.scrollTo(0, top);
  }, [currPostIdx]);

  return (
    <>
      <ul className="navbar">
        {posts.map((p, i) => (
          <li key={p.title} onClick={() => selectPost(i)}>
            {p.title}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div ref={containerRef}>
        {posts.map((p, idx) => (
          <Post key={p.title} post={p} idx={idx} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const Post = ({ idx, post }) => (
  <div
    id={post.title}
    className="post"
    style={{ backgroundColor: `#${idx + 5}${idx * 3}${idx * 4}` }}
  >
    <h4>{post.title}</h4>
  </div>
);
```

Demo [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jmbidx?file=src%2FApp.js)

The seond approach makes use of hash navigation and hence it has not to calculate the position of the element manually:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="navbar">
        {posts.map((p) => (
          <a href={`#${p.title}`}>{p.title}</a>
        ))}
      </div>
      {posts.map((p, idx) => (
        <Post key={p.title} post={p} idx={idx} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const Post = ({ idx, post }) => (
  <div
    id={post.title}
    className="post"
    style={{ backgroundColor: `#${idx + 5}${idx * 3}${idx * 4}` }}
  >
    <h4>{post.title}</h4>
  </div>
);
```

Demo [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xxeygg?file=src%2FApp.js)